# Connect 4 webcams to a USB HUB

Tags: usb, camera, hub

I have a USB2.0 hub with 4 ports connected to my computer. Can I connect 4 USB cameras to this hub at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the resolution (ie output) of the USB cameras and if you are going to be using them simultaneously, but yes, this is quite practical.

Comment: Sorry but the most important part is missing. For that reason, I gave this a -1. See my answer.

Comment: You raise a valid point about power, but the way you went about doing it is dickish.  I put to you that my answer is correct, albeit incomplete.  Many (most?) hubs are powered,and even if they are not, depending on the camera and usage it will still work provided you are not using them simultanously.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the USB hub. A usb hub that draws its power from the usb port itself might run into problems because 4 webcams can draw more power from the usb port than it can provide, especially if more devices are connected to this usb hub (given it has more ports obviously)

If the usb hub has a power connection too and its being used, it will sort out the problem. In that case it most likely works, but it does depend on how you use them, like at the same time and what resolution. It also draws a bit of system resources, but if your pc can play a 3d game (even if its an old one), it will work.

Comment: And as long as the combined data stream of the 4 cameras don't exceed the available bandwidth limit of the usb host controller that this hub is connected to.  The question of whether or not the hub is powered, and whether or not the cameras exceed the bandwidth for that hub becomes moot if this hub is not the only device connected to the host controller.  A single host controller will only have 480 megabits per second available.  So plug this hub with four cameras, and then a flashdisk or external drive into another port on the same controller... game over.